# Rendering a MapContainer on several subpages results in error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-leaflet

I'm having some issues with MapContainer from react-leaflet throwing errors at me in my app.

I have a tabel of events, that links to a page with event details, this details page implements a map with the following component:

```
export function MapWithPoints(props: Props) {
  const { points } = props

  return (
    <MapContainer scrollWheelZoom={false} style={{ height: 300, width: '100vw' }}>
      <InnerMap points={points} />
    </MapContainer>
  )
}
```

InnerMap is defined as:

```
function InnerMap(props: Props) {
  const { points } = props
  const leafletMap = useMap()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (leafletMap && points.length) {
      const pointArray: L.LatLngTuple[] = points.map((item) => [
        item.lat,
        item.lng,
      ])
      const bounds = L.latLngBounds(pointArray)
      leafletMap.fitBounds(bounds)
    }
  }, [points, leafletMap])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      {points
        .filter((poi) => poi.lat && poi.lng)
        .map((poi) => (
          <Marker
            position={[poi.lat, poi.lng]}
            key={`${poi.id}_${poi.lat}_${poi.lng}`}
            icon={poi.icon ? poi.icon : DefaultIcon}
          >
            {poi.description ? <Popup>{poi.description}</Popup> : null}
          </Marker>
        ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

The map works when I go to the first (random) entry in my list of events, the event page loads like it should, but if I go back and then choose another event page, MapContainer throws an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Map container is already initialized.
    at NewClass._initContainer (Map.js:1092:1)
    at NewClass.initialize (Map.js:136:1)
    at new NewClass (Class.js:24:1)
    at MapContainer.js:31:1
    at commitAttachRef (react-dom.development.js:23645:1)
    at safelyAttachRef (react-dom.development.js:22891:1)
    at reappearLayoutEffectsOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23545:1)
    at reappearLayoutEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24838:1)
    at reappearLayoutEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24826:1)
    at commitLayoutEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24649:1)
```

I'm using react 18, and react-leaflet 4.0.0

Is there something I have missed in the setup?

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in 4.0.0, but even when using the latest version, I still get the error now and then. A workaround is to have a unique key on Map Container, for example timestamp. But this result in a memory leak, as each time a map is loaded it consumes more memory